# How to break/cut a circle in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a circle and would like to cut/break it to get a start-end-point curve represeting the circle before.

Attention: I don't want to create a circle using a line! See above: I already have a circle and want to interrupt it.

Any ideas, how to do this?

When I use the curve ID and delete points, then the circle stays connected. But  this is not what I want.

What I have:
[image: What I have:]

Comment: That looks like a Curve Primitive > Arc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how feasible it is in your setup, but you could do a quick *Curve to Mesh* before the *Delete Geometry* and then a *Mesh to Curve* again after - this will interrupt the cyclical tendency of the spline and "replace" it already disconnected:

[image: Curves]

Comment: This perfect! Thank you Chris! I was about to get the solution myself, but didn't know the mesh trick...